# In Watson conversation service, how to prevent from matching to the wrong intent, example is included

Tags: watson-conversation

I have a simple flow where I want to give the response based on the input to an entity ( in my case @language). Why is the response mapping to an intent ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the second condition you have created.

```
@language:java AND #how_to_develop
```

When the user enters in the text "Java", the intent of the text is checked again. Because the intent is different, it will never hit that node.

You can solve this by just setting your condition to:

```
@language:java
```

As you have already detected the earlier intent.

In your application, you can stop the second response from doing an intent check by passing back the `intents[]` object from the previous call.